# TIdHTTP->Get() , Server ignores parameters

Tags: c++builder, indy, indy10, c++builder-xe6

I've got this query:

https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty.json?conditions[krs_podmioty.nip]=7282827109

In a browser, it works OK, showing data specific for the given `nip` number.

But in Indy, I get a response as if the query part was omitted:

https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty.json

I've tried this so far:

```cpp
BurL = "https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty.json?conditions[krs_podmioty.nip]=7282827109";
```

```cpp
BurL = TIdURI::URLEncode("https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty.json?conditions[krs_podmioty.nip]=7282827109");
```

End even raw urlencoded data:

```cpp
BurL= "https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty.json?conditions%5Bkrs_podmioty.nip%5D=7282827109";
```

Code:

```cpp
try {
     Resp = IdHTTPKrs->Get(BurL);
    } catch (EIdHTTPProtocolException& e) {
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
}
```

What's wrong, and how can I fix this? Or, maybe I am too tired already and am missing something obvious?

I suspect there is something with the `[]` part of the query, but I am just guessing here. Similar queries without the `[]` work OK.

I am using C++Builder XE6 pro, with Indy 10.6.0.512

Comment: "And FYI, your Indy version is out of date" It appears as this is crucial information, after upgrade indy i am getting correct results. Forumulate it into an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Indy version is out of date.  The latest version, at the time of this writing, is 10.6.2.5448.  Using the latest version, I can't reproduce your issue.  Both URL encodings return the same data for me.  As they should be, since a web server is required to decode urlencoded characters when processing the requested URL. `conditions%5Bkrs_podmioty.nip%5D=7282827109` and `conditions[krs_podmioty.nip]=7282827109` *should* be getting processed the exact same way by the server, as they are sematically identical data.